# What's the difference between "spectromicroscopy" and "microspectroscopy"?

Tags: definition, spectroscopy, microscopy

[Both](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/microspectroscope) [definitions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spectromicroscopy) that I found are rather vague.

(Related question: [What's the difference between microscopy and spectroscopy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165814/whats-the-difference-between-microscopy-and-spectroscopy))

Comment: [Spectromicroscopy](https://code.google.com/p/spectromicroscopy/)

Comment: I'm closing this entry for various reasons. Partly as a _duplicate_ as it is receiving duplicate answers (now deleted). Moreover, soft-questions about terminology rarely have unique answers, and hence fit poorly on a Q&A site. The short answer often is: Different authors use different terminology.

Comment: @Qmechanic, I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: Please, open your eyes. They are different questions. Yes, first three indentations was copied and pasted here. But the actual answer is in the last indentation which is unique. You could just delete first three indents and instead make a link to related post, but deleting the whole answer is not reasonable.