# What's the difference between microscopy and spectroscopy?

Tags: definition, spectroscopy, microscopy

Both methods collect particles or electromagnetic waves, and in both methods it's possible to reconstruct a 2D image, which may represent morphology ([AFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_force_microscopy), [LEED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-energy_electron_diffraction) for example), electronic structure ([STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope), [EFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_force_microscope) for example), magnetic structure ([MFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_force_microscope), [XPEEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy) for example) etc.

But is there a reason (other than historic) to divide [materials analysis methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_materials_analysis_methods) between microscopy and spectroscopy?

(Related question: [What's the difference between "spectromicroscopy" and "microspectroscopy"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/whats-the-difference-between-spectromicroscopy-and-microspectroscopy))

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of microscopy is to observe things that cannot be or are hardly observed by naked eye. To justify the purpose one can utilize everything that suits the purpose. For example, it can be different light paths coming from different parts of a sample or different reflection from different parts of a sample etc. Or in terms of AFM it can be different interaction forces between tip and different parts of a sample. So whatever physical quantity which varies depending on the position on a sample can be utilized to produce an image. And so can be utilized different spectroscopic features (intensity, wavelength, phase, FWHM of a peak etc.).

The main purpose of spectroscopy is to understand how matter responds to light (or electrons, whatever), to find one-to-one correspondence between spectra and material internal structures, to classify thus materials according to their reaction on light and so on. In this case acquiring image is not necessary, just spectra would be enough.

As a conclusion, microscopy and spectroscopy differ by their historically initial purposes. However they can cooperate effectively with each other. For example, as was said above, one can make an image utilizing the power of spectroscopy. Or, vice versa, one can use the power of microscopy to acquire spectrum from a tiny spot of a sample (either on surface or inside).

And here is the answer to the [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165468/whats-the-difference-between-spectromicroscopy-and-microspectroscopy):

Taking all of these into account, considering given two words, we should separate prefix from the main part of the word. For example, in the word "microspectroscopy" the main part is "spectroscopy" and the prefix is "micro", so it is spectroscopy in the first instance. But it utilizes the power of microscopy. I think you can now deduce the meaning of "spectromicroscopy".

Answer (score 0):

1. Microscopy is just to visualise the smaller objects while the spectroscopy is the study of the spectrum obtained from the materials
2. microscopy is the study of materials whereas spectroscopy is the study of energy
3. Microscopy may or may not use the light/energy to visualise the mass whereas spectroscopy uses the optical arrangements to visualise the spectral/energy lines